# Find a word of a list in a sentence of another list and replace it in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list

I have existing two lists as below:

```
list_a = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven',...]

list_content = ['This is 1st sentence with one.',
'This is 2nd sentence with seven.',
'This is 3rd sentence with one and two.',
'This is 4th sentence with three, five, and six.',...]
```

The idea is to find a word from **list_a** in each sentence of **list_content** and replace them into **'__'** for exact match.

The output should be like this:

```
list_output = ['This is 1st sentence with ___.',
'This is 2nd sentence with ___.',
'This is 3rd sentence with ___ and ___.',
'This is 4th sentence with ___, ___, and ___.',...]
```

My attempt using **re.sub**:

```
for each_sent in list_content:
  for word in list_a:
     result = re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', '__', each)
  print result
```

It doesn't seem to be replaced as in output.

Comment: change `result = re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', '__', each)` to `each_sent = re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', '__', each_sent)` and `print result` to `print each_sent`

Comment: `result = re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', '__', each)` change `each` to `each_sent`

Comment: You're a bit of KungFu Panda!! You just saved my life! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
import re

list_a = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven',]

list_content = ['This is 1st sentence with one.',
'This is 2nd sentence with seven.',
'This is 3rd sentence with one and two.',
'This is 4th sentence with three, five, and six.',]
list_output = []
for each_sent in list_content:
    for word in list_a:
        each_sent = re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', '__', each_sent)
    list_output.append(each_sent)
print list_output
```

Output:

```
['This is 1st sentence with __.', 'This is 2nd sentence with __.', 'This is 3rd sentence with __ and __.', 'This is 4th sentence with __, __, and __.']
```

Comment: @htetmyet Glad I can help!! be sure to accept my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Avoid loop inside a loop. I wrote this keeping performance in mind

```
re_str_a = re.compile( '\b' + '\b|\b'.join(list_a) + '\b')
for each in list_content:
   print re_str_a.sub('___', each)
```

Comment: You will need to add the `\b` in front and at the end of each word before compile to avoid subbing `one` in `phone`. I would use this `re.compile('\b' + '\b|\b'.join(list_a) + '\b')`

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Edited my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

How about without any loops (https://regex101.com/r/pvwuUw/1):

```
In [4]: sep = "||||"

In [5]: re.sub(r'\b' + '|'.join(list_a) + r'\b', '__', sep.join(list_content)).split(sep)
Out[5]: 
['This is 1st sentence with __.',
 'This is 2nd sentence with __.',
 'This is 3rd sentence with __ and __.',
 'This is 4th sentence with __, __, and __.']
```

The idea is to join the `list_content` with a separator and after replacement split the string with the same separator again.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

use python-textops package :

```
from textops import *
print list_content >> sed('|'.join(list_a),'__')
```